# How to take continous(scheduled) back up from sqlserver azure portal

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-storage

Anybody help me, How to take continuous backup from AZURE portal.(I don't have virtual machine in AZURE) It should be like scheduler running back side and will take back up from sql server in month interval.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Database automatically creates database backups.

If you want it to create backup in month interval, you could upgrade your [database service tier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-service-tiers) to Standard or Premium, SQL Database keeps existing backups until they are 35 days old. It keeps new backups as they occur for 35 days.

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-automated-backups#how-often-do-backups-happen).

Comment: Thanks Joy Wang ... How to store sql backups to azure storage account?

Comment: @SivaNaidu You could refer to this [article](https://gooroo.io/GoorooTHINK/Article/11010/Backing-up-SQL-Server-databases-to-Azure-Storage-Services/4100#.WsNUqohuaUk) to learn how to Back up SQL Server databases to Azure Storage Services.If you want to do it easier, you cloud use this [tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40740).

Comment: @SivaNaidu Any update this case? If you think my answer is helpful, you could mark it as answer to help more community members to find. Thanks.